# How to upload "text/plain" string in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm desperately trying to upload a plain (text/plain) string in Web API and my Controller is simply refusing to do the routing correctly. All I'm getting is a 404 (Not Found) HTTP error (I was so happy all the "Get" methods were working out of the box :-( )

Here are my routes:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "IntegraApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ServComAdminApi",
            routeTemplate: "admin/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "admin", action = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ServComApi",
            routeTemplate: "{id}/{action}",
            constraints: new { id = @"\d+" },
            defaults: new { controller = "servcom", action = "info" }
        );

        // Get rid of XML responses
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
}
```

The pertinent route is the last one that maps to the "servcom" controller. I'm porting a custom written HTTP server that followed that routing pattern ("id/action"). It is working for all "get" methods. I can get a list of "users" for the equipment with id "10" by just using: `http://localhost:49410/10/users`... But it's not working when I try to upload "string data". This is the pertinent method on my controller:

```
public class ServcomController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut, HttpPost]
    public string Vis(long idTerm)
    {
        return "PUT/POST Vis for: " + idTerm;
    }
}
```

It's stripped down to the bare minimum. I'm not even reading the actual string data. Since I won't be sending form encoded data, just a plain string (this API is currently used under 3G so any byte savings are great as we need to minimize data-plan usage), I didn't use [FromBody] attributes as it won't work at all.

This is the client code used to test it:

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace TestPutPostString
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sending 'HELLO WORLD!'");
            var wc = new WebClient();
            var res = wc.UploadString("http://localhost:49410/101/vis", "PUT", "HELLO WORLD!");
            Console.WriteLine("Response: " + res);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

It fails with: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

The above code works perfectly with my hand-written HTTP server, which uses TcpServer and was written from scratch for the specific needs of this API (I'm migrating it to Web.API after 2 years of use since it will be easier to host it on Azure this way). Using this same sample program with hand-written HTTP stack, the body of the message, when hitting the server, does indeed have "HELLO WORLD!". Why isn't it being routed to the ServComController.Vis() method?

Am I sending it wrong? Does WebClient.UploadString() works in other unpredictable ways? Or is my controller method signature wrong? Is the route wrong? What am I missing!?!? :-)

Comment: Without (and sometimes even with) url routing, the server won't know where to send your request. Try changing your function name to `PUT()` or `POST()` to match the http method

Comment: Does `UploadString` work if you use POST instead of PUT?  (if I recall correctly, PUT is blocked on IIS by default)

Comment: @JLevett I can't change the method name. It's a well established command on the protocol in question and it's being used by thousands of devices already on the "wild".

Comment: @McGarnagle it doesn't work with either PUT or POST.

Answer (score 2):

IF you want to avoid the pain of Action Selection you could change your signature to be,

```
public class ServcomController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut, HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Vis(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var idTerm = request.GetRouteData().Values["idTerm"];
        var body = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        return "PUT/POST Vis for: " + idTerm;
    }
}
```

Comment: The route worked if I did this, but trying to get the value of the idTerm by the "route data" returns null. It seems that it is really not resolving the action nor the id selection. The route, although simple, is not working. I can live with that... But I still don't know what is not working. I can achieve the same result by declaring the method as `public HttpResponseMessage Vis()`...

Comment: it was thank to you that I realized the problem! I named the "id" parameter used on the route as idTerm on the method. That's why it wasn't matching the route! Now I've changed it to `public HttpResponseMessage Vis(long id)`and it works! I don't know how to match the string passed on the body, but I'll read it manually from the request. Nothing like a good answer and a couple of beers to put you back on the right track!

Answer (score 1):

Darrel Miller provided quite a nice solution which is not the actual answer, but I guess will end up with lots of more upvotes than my own answer to my own question. I wasn't aware we could "avoid the pain of Action Selection" by using using a parameter of the type `HttpRequestMessage` ! This is quite nice and I can see a lot of scenarios where it will be really, really useful.

But that's not the only reason his answer will get a lot more upvotes: this is because my question was silly! I did a very stupid mistake.

This is the route:

```
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ServComApi",
        routeTemplate: "{id}/{action}",
        constraints: new { id = @"\d+" },
        defaults: new { controller = "servcom", action = "info" }
    );
```

This is the Method I was trying to map the route to:

```
public class ServcomController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut, HttpPost]
    public string Vis(long idTerm)
    {
        return "PUT/POST Vis for: " + idTerm;
    }
}
```

Of course it won't match! In the route I've used "id" as the parameter, and in this method I've used "idTerm" as the parameter, so there was really no action on the ServComController which matched the route!

The solution was simply to change it to:

```
public class ServcomController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPut, HttpPost]
    public string Vis(long id) // << "idTerm" to "id"
    {
        return "PUT/POST Vis for: " + idTerm;
    }
}
```

And since the body is not form encoded, I won't be able to use [FromBody]string data, because it expects form data. The final solution will be to read the body from the request using a good, old `StreamReader` for that. I'll update the solution with the full code later today.